# Neo4j browser seems disoriented when using 4.0-enterprise docker

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used docker 4.0-enterprise and logged into the browser on a **remote server**.

Using, `:dbs` shows databases on the **remote server** correctly

BUT, `show databases` shows databases on **localhost**

Is this a bug or a "feature" ?

What do I have to do to see databases on remote host when I use `show databases` ?

[image]